# How to run typescript compiler as a package.json script without grunt or gulp

Tags: typescript, package.json

I don't want to use grunt or gulp to compile ts files. I just want to do it in my package.json something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc main.ts dist/"
  },
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 77):

> "build": "tsc main.ts dist/"

Highly recommend you use `tsconfig.json` and then the `-p` compiler option to build your code.
Look at: [Compilation-Context](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/compilation-context)

### Setup

Here is the setup for using `tsc` with NPM scripts

**init**

```
npm init
npm install typescript --save
```

And then in your package.json **add some scripts**:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "start": "npm run build -- -w"
},
```

## Use

- For build only: `npm run build`
- For building + live watching : `npm start`

Enjoy

Comment: Link is broken now. Do you have a new one?

Comment: just go up one level on the directory, exclude the filename and the project will load:   https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/tree/master/docs

Comment: To generage the tsconfig.json : `yarn run tsc --init` (or replace yarn with npm if you are using npm)

Comment: Just a note, the `./src` within the build script should point to the directory with your tsconfig. Thanks a lot for this :)

Comment: This should be:

npm install --save-dev typescript

You don't want to make typescript a run time dependency

Comment: You can also change ```./src``` to point to your config directly, usually ```./tsconfig.json```

Comment: My bad on the `./src`. I've updated the answer now. I think TypeScript used to create the tsconfig.json in the src folder and doesn't do that anymore ‍♂️ OR I might have been wrong 

Answer (score 11):

If you want to compile and run, you can use the [ts-node module](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

```
npm install --save-dev ts-node 
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

And run with:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts"
},
```

All other typescripts files that index.ts has imported (along with imports from index.ts dependencies) will be compiled and executed.