# Typescript abstract class error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: compiler-errors, typescript, abstract

When I am trying to specify an abstract class in typescript, like:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {

}
```

I receive the following compilation error:

```
AbstractFoo.ts(1,10): error TS1005: ';'
```

My package.json contains:

```
"typescript": "^1.6.2"
```

as a dependency.

What can the reason for this error be?

Comment: What is the output of `tsc --version`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My package.json contains:

If you want to use the `tsc` version from `package.json` you should run:

`./node_modules/.bin/tsc --watch`

That code works fine with TS 1.6+.

## More

You can even do a fancier setup like : [How to run typescript compiler as a package.json script without grunt or gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749952/how-to-run-typescript-compiler-as-a-package-json-script-without-grunt-or-gulp/31756993#31756993)