# How to run ts script with package.json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, package.json, npm-scripts

I try to run typescript files with just a package.json file. So a minimum setup for running typescript files.

I just have a singel file: index.ts:

```
console.clear();
console.log("nic to see you!!");
```

and package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

But if I try to do :

npm start, I will get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\TypeScript\Todo\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Todo@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Todo@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User.USER-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-24T11_22_12_024Z-debug.log
PS D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\TypeScript\Todo>
```

So my question is: what I have to change that it will compile?

Thank you

oke, I have it now like this:

packagege.json:

```
{
  "name": "Todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build":"tsc -p ./src", 
    "start": "npm run build -- -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

And I installed typescript

and I do: npm start. I still get this error:

```
 npm run build -- -w


> Todo@1.0.0 build D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\TypeScript\Todo
> tsc -p ./src "-w"

error TS5057: Cannot find a tsconfig.json file at the specified directory: './src'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Todo@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p ./src "-w"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Todo@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User.USER-PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-24T11_33_38_340Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Todo@1.0.0 start: `npm run build -- -w`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

oke, I have it now like this:

```
{
  "name": "Todo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc main.ts dist/",
    "start": "npm run build -- -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  }
}
```

and if I do this: npm run. I see this output:

```
> Todo@1.0.0 build D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\TypeScript\Todo
> tsc main.ts dist/ "-w"

[1:46:58 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

error TS6053: File 'dist/.ts' not found.

[1:46:59 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

oke, I see now this:

```
> Todo@1.0.0 build D:\Mijn Documents\UDEMY\TypeScript\Todo
> tsc -p ./ "-w"

[2:00:31 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[2:00:34 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

But where I can see the results then? Will be nice to go to some port, like: localhost:4200 in the browser, but how to do that?

Comment: Install Typescript and compile it first?

Comment: Or use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node. Or just rename the file to .js, as there are no types in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run typescript compiler as a package.json script without grunt or gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749952/how-to-run-typescript-compiler-as-a-package-json-script-without-grunt-or-gulp)

Comment: thank you. But that is not the problem. Because I can just run ANgular projects. I already have node.js installed

Comment: check typescript setup video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zhTKGk2Kf8&list=PLAAFB8z-Xn4Eh6EiE7ihg-pCko-wty845

Answer (score 11):

Try typing in the terminal as follows:

```
ts-node ./src/index.ts
```

Or, try the following modifications to the "start" script:

```
"start": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
```

Comment: `ts-node` is an npm package that needs to be installed: `npm install --save-dev ts-node`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!!

the trick was this in the package.json:

```
"start": "tsc-watch --onsuccess \"node dist/index.js\""
```